# Lots of schema warnings after project upgraded to SDK 2.6

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

After upgrading my cloud projects to Azure SDK 2.6. (via button in project properties window), everything works just fine, except I am getting like hundred of these warnings for *.cscfg files:

```
The complexType 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration:AccessControlElement' has already been declared.
The complexType 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration:AddressAssignmentsElement' has already been declared.
The complexType 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration:Certificate' has already been declared.
```

etc. for many more elements.

Already tried Clean, Rebuild, close-open VS... with no success. It doesnt affect functionality of the project, but it is really annoying to have Error list full of these things.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so guys from [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/53845279-5d3d-4caa-ad64-cc772779fd47/lots-of-schema-warnings-after-project-upgraded-to-azure-sdk-26?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required) helped me solve this one.

1. Check SchemaVersion value in service definition file, it should be "schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6" (this one was OK for me)
2. Open service definition file as XML, right click on it, Properties -> Schemas. In the window (see pic), leave only ServiceDefinitionSchema26.xsd checked ("use this schema"), set all other versions to Automatic (unechecked). Restart Visual studio and warnings are gone.

[image]